# Apache POI add new column to pivot table

Tags: apache-poi

I have a pivot table which has column labels "Total sales" and "Individual Sales". I want to add a new column to the pivot table to calculate the percentage of sales (Individual sales / Total sales *100). I am having problem adding this new calculated column to pivot table.

I think my problem is with the following line of code.

```
ctCacheField.setFormula("'Individual Sales'/'Total Sales' * 100")  in
addFormulaToCache method.
```

Note: Individual Sales and Total Sales in the above line is the column names i have in pivot table.

Here is my complete code. When i run this code, it generates the Excel. But when i open the Excel, i get an error and i don't see the Pivot table.

```
        AreaReference a=new AreaReference("Data!A1:C6");
        /* Define the starting Cell Reference for the Pivot Table */
        CellReference b=new CellReference("A1");
        /* Create the Pivot Table */
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet1.createPivotTable(a,b);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
        // 1. Add Formula to cache
         addFormulaToCache(pivotTable);
        // 2. Add PivotField for Formula column
         addPivotFieldForNewColumn(pivotTable);
         // 3. Add all column labels before our function..
          pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 2, "Total Sales");
          pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1, "Individual Sales");
          addFormulaColumn(pivotTable);

        /* Write output to file */ 
        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\POI_XLS_Pivot_Example.xlsx")); //create XLSX file
        new_workbook.write(output_file);//write excel document to output stream
        output_file.close(); //close the file
}


private static void addFormulaToCache(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable) {
    CTCacheFields ctCacheFields = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields();
    CTCacheField ctCacheField = ctCacheFields.addNewCacheField();
    ctCacheField.setName("Field1"); // Any field name
    **ctCacheField.setFormula("'Individual Sales'/'Total Sales' * 100");** //This is where the problem could be
    ctCacheField.setDatabaseField(false);
    ctCacheField.setNumFmtId(0);
    ctCacheFields.setCount(ctCacheFields.sizeOfCacheFieldArray()); //!!! update count of fields directly
}

private static void addPivotFieldForNewColumn(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable) {
    CTPivotField pivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().addNewPivotField();
    pivotField.setDataField(true);
    pivotField.setDragToCol(false);
    pivotField.setDragToPage(false);
    pivotField.setDragToRow(false);
    pivotField.setShowAll(false);
    pivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
}

private static void addFormulaColumn(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable) {
    CTDataFields dataFields;
    if(pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields() != null) {
        dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getDataFields();
    } else {
        // can be null if we have not added any column labels yet
        dataFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewDataFields();
    }
    CTDataField dataField = dataFields.addNewDataField();
    dataField.setName("%age Group Difference");
    // set index of cached field with formula - it is the last one!!!
    dataField.setFld(pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCount()-1);
    dataField.setBaseItem(0);
    dataField.setBaseField(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a follow-on from another question: [XSSF (POI) - Adding “formula” column to pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684662/xssf-poi-adding-formula-column-to-pivot-table)

The missing piece to your question is that "Individual Sales" and "Total Sales" are made-up column names in your pivot table.  Assuming your source is:

```
Fruit  | Price
Apple  | 1.5
Orange | 1
```

Your formula to get Price * 2 would naturally be "'Price' * 2" irregardless of the name in the pivot table.  If you truly wish to reference the made-up name, your formula becomes more complicated.  For your pivot table in cell A1, a reference to "Individual Sales" would be:

```
GETPIVOTDATA("Individual Sales",$A$1,<Filter Name>,<Filter Value>)
```

But this defeats the purpose of a pivot table.
As an additional note, should you desire, all three pieces of valerii ryzhuk's answer can be put into a single function.  They don't need to be split-up except to explain the answer.